# Multiple values/dimensions vs multiple layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

"**Supporting Multiple Android Screens**". I found multiple links on how to develop android apps for multiple screens but I'm still skeptical.

Is it better to have multiple layouts or one default layout with multiple res-values (`dimens.xml`).

(I personally think that multiple layouts is very tedious).

The app **only** has portrait mode and does **not** include tablets. Any thoughts on that will be appreciated.

Comment: Since you should very, very rarely be specifying sizes exactly of anything rather than relatively, a separate dimens file won't solve it.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the reply. But let's say for instance you want to have your view marginStart of a certain view be 10dp, or the size of a certain button be 50dp. One layout with multiple dimens.xml for different sizes could do the job too right?

Comment: Oh for that kind of stuff sure. In fact for that type of stuff you generally don't even change it-  you tend to want it to stay the same physical size, so you just specify it in dp and don't need to override it.

Comment: What do you mean by "that type of stuff you generally don't even change it"?

Comment: 10dp is the same physical size (1/16th of an inch) on all devices.  Thats a good amount of padding on any device, you'd typically just keep it at that.  Same for the height of the button (just under 1/3 of an inch).  Frequently (although not always) you'd just keep those values the same across devices.  Especially the padding/margin value.

Comment: @Reda M what screens does it include you already said tabs are not there?

Comment: @CharuකI will be targeting handset devices (post honeycomb +3.2), it will be portrait only (No tablets, not landscape, no wearables, and no TVs).

Comment: @GabeSechan Well, for instance, having a button height 50dp is showing different outputs for a 4.7 inches devices VS a 6 inches on the IDE preview, but I'm about to run it to see if it's going to be similar to the preview or not.

Comment: 1 dp is 1/160th of an inch on any device. Px is what  differs by dpi

Comment: @GabeSechan I agree, so going back to the question that means that one default layout file with different dimens.xml that Android OS triggers at launch time from different res-values will do the work? (sorry for being tedious, I'm trying to have a good understanding here)